# Why does vim sometimes display linebreaks incorrectly?

Tags: vim

I have a long line of text in vim, soft-wrap is on, I've done `:set linebreak`, and `breakat` has the right value.

The problem is, when I edit some text in the middle of the "paragraph", the lines don't wrap at word boundaries anymore.

**Example:**

1) Cursor is in the middle of the line:

[image: Before editing text]

2) I type `cw` and the linebreaks change:

[image: After "cw" command]

It stays like that when I go back to normal mode, but wraps correctly again when the cursor leaves the line.

This does not happen if I add text in the middle, or do a command like `dw` - seemingly just commands that delete some text and enter insert mode.

The problem began on a fresh install of Fedora 21, but my `.vimrc` is unchanged from my previous computer, where I did not have this problem.

How do I restore the correct behavior, or is this perhaps a bug in the Fedora package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, this is a bug, that has been fixed with [7.4.576](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/detail?r=749fc929da45d07efc5352dd8a0c00f8ed9f2163)

Comment: Thank you - I just found this out myself a second ago. Here's a [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/Bh0Nd321JYE/69kCLnzb3iYJ) to the thread on it in case it's useful to anyone else.